# What are the Business applications of Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, business-intelligence

I am finding it increasingly difficult to find any specific material on the business applications of Neural Networks. This makes sense because many businesses try to keep their secrets to themselves, however, I have been wondering the following question: How do businesses use Neural Networks and what specific examples show their usage?

If anyone can provide some light on this matter, I would very much be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Geodetic classification using neural networks attempts to infer useful information from multispectral satellite and other imaging. The results are used in agriculture, mining, civil engineering, simulation, etc. Some search results are seen [here](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=geodetic+classification+using+neural+networks).